# Why does this complex number need to be simplified before computing its power?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

While playing with this [mathematics.stackexchange.com problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2039286/if-x-frac1x-frac1-sqrt52-then-x2000-frac1x2000) I ran into an intriguing behavior. The problem is about proving that
$$
x+ \frac1x=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\Rightarrow x^{2000}+ \frac1{x^{2000}}=2.
$$
The equation on the left admits
$$
y=\frac{1}{4} \left(1+\sqrt{5}+i \sqrt{10-2
   \sqrt{5}}\right)
$$
as a solution. A critical argument in solving the linked problem is the fact that 
$$
y^5=-1\text{ and therefore }y^{2000}=(-1)^{400}=1.
$$
Now, asking Mathematica about all this yields

```
sol = Solve[x + 1/x == 1/2 (Sqrt[5] + 1), x];
y = x /. sol[[1]]
Simplify[y]

1/4 (1 + Sqrt[5] - I Sqrt[16 - (-1 - Sqrt[5])^2])
1/4 (1 + Sqrt[5] - I Sqrt[10 - 2 Sqrt[5]])
```

So far, so good, although I wonder why I need to invoque `Simplify`. However, computing $y^5$ requires `Simplify`ing in order to obtain $-1$:

```
y^5
Simplify[y^5]

(1 + Sqrt[5] + I Sqrt[10 - 2 Sqrt[5]])^5/1024
-1
```

and $y^{2000}$ is even more problematic

```
y^2000
Simplify[y^2000]
Simplify[y^5]^400

(1 + Sqrt[5] + I Sqrt[10 - 2 Sqrt[5]])^2000/1318(...)76
(1 + Sqrt[5] + I Sqrt[10 - 2 Sqrt[5]])^2000/1318(...)76
1
```

Moreover, just asking

```
y^2000 == Simplify[y^5]^400
```

does not return an answer, just

```
(1 + Sqrt[5] + I Sqrt[10 - 2 Sqrt[5]])^2000/1318(...)76==1
```

Note that it does not appear to be related to the fact that $2000$ is *large*, replacing it by $20$ shows the same pattern.

My question is: what is going on? Why do I have to *force simplify* a complex number in order to get the correct result?

*For the sake of conveinience here is my entire code:*

```
sol = Solve[x + 1/x == 1/2 (Sqrt[5] + 1), x];
y = x /. sol[[1]]
Simplify[y]
"Testing y^5"
y^5
Simplify[y^5]
"Testing y^2000"
y^2000
Simplify[y^2000]
Simplify[y^5]^400
y^2000 == Simplify[y^5]^400
```

*ps.* I am running 11.0.1.0

Comment: With version 11.0.1, `Simplify[y^100]` yields `1`.

Comment: Put a `FullSimplify` on your initial definition of y, and it's all clean and obvious.  In general Mathematica does the least amount of work to get you your answer on time.  Simplification can be a hard task which takes a very long time.  It is left to the operator to choose whether or not to do this extra work.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Same here. However `Simplify[y^100]` does not.

Comment: @wxffles Thanks for your comment. In the present case the appearent simplicity of $y$ may be misleading. Do you suggest applying `Simplify` or `FullSimplify` on a systematic basis, even before testing something like $y^{2000}==1$ ?

Comment: @wxffles  `FullSimplify[y^2000]` does not give 1 for me.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I mean `FullSimplify[y]^2000`.  I am suggesting that there is no easy answer, and you have to use your judgement of whether to simplify or not.

Comment: @wxffles  Very nice.  Write it up as an answer.

Comment: @bbgodfrey I believe the question implied equation is in error and the error is over complicating matters. My guess for the correct implication  is in the answer I posted.

Comment: Thanks. As I now understand how to get around the problem, I still have to come to grasp with how to detect such a situation may be arising where I would have to (full)simplify some expression. If I had not gone throught the math, or if the expressions had been more complex, I might not have thought of using `Simplify` and therefore ended up with a wrong answer. Maybe sprinkling my code with `FullSimplify`'s is the way to go, but it remains intellectually awkward. Of course that may just be a sign that my understanding of what Mathematica does is not totally correct.

Answer (score 4):

I think the easiest way to proceed is:

```
{a, b} = x /. Solve[x + 1/x == (1 + Sqrt[5])/2, x];
s = ArcTan[FullSimplify[#2/#1 & @@ ReIm[a]]]
t = ArcTan[FullSimplify[#2/#1 & @@ ReIm[b]]]
```

Now s and t are: $-\pi/5$ and $\pi/5$ respectively and $x=e^{\pm i \pi/5}$, hence $x^{2000}=x^{-2000}=1$ and the RHS follows.

Or perhaps even simpler by noting: for $|z|=1$, $(z+1/z)/2=\cos(z)$:

```
z = FullSimplify[ArcCos[(1 + Sqrt[5])/4]]
```

yields the $z=\pi/5$ with same implication.

Comment: Thanks! Another useful step is `ToPolarCoordinates@ReIm[{a, b}] // FullSimplify`